# Trouble with a formula in Sheets to forecast shipment arrival

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have big trouble making my formula works and I am pretty sure that this is simple.
So simple that I am litteraly struggling on it for weeks now.. So I give up :'(

**Let me explain:**
I am using sheets to schedule when my shipment ETA. So I have these informations:

- "**CMD**": which is when the customer made his command
- "**PM**": which is just an opt-in to know if the command were made after noon
- "**SHIPMENT**": which is just a choice of tranporters
- "**WORKDAYS**": which is the number of workdays for each transporter. linked with "shipment"
- "**ETA**": which is the Formula I want to make to have the accurate estimated time of arrival

(see image below where I show the correct results in ETA)

[image: google Sheets example]

[Here you can find the Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IdpuhR44UaNUz9U8xD9mzWXLiJLAF0lHd9gPPHhNANU/edit?usp=sharing)

**Things to know:**

- workday delivery is each day except on sunday
- if "PM"=true, then you can add a day to delivery (see raw 2 and 3 on the example)
- if "CMD" is: friday+"PM"=true then the count starts on next monday (see raw 6 and 7 on the example)
- if "CMD" is: saturday or sunday then the count starts on next monday (see raw 8 and 9 on the example)

**Things I've tried so far:**

- a lot of formulas to say different things. I tried the barbarian way (with holidays and different workdays in sheet 'data v2'):

> =if(isblank(B7);""; if(C7=true;ifs(G7="Mondial Relay";WORKDAY.INTL(B7;H7+1;'data v2'!$K$4;'data v2'!$M$3:$M$13);G7="Chrono 24h";workday.intl(B7;H7+1;'data v2'!$K$3;'data v2'!$M$3:$M$13);G7="Colissimo";workday.intl(B7;H7+1;'data v2'!$K$5;'data v2'!$M$3:$M$13));ifs(G7="Mondial Relay";WORKDAY.INTL(B7;H7;'data v2'!$K$4;'data v2'!$M$3:$M$13);G7="Chrono 24h";workday.intl(B7;H7;'data v2'!$K$3;'data v2'!$M$3:$M$13);G7="Colissimo";workday.intl(B7;H7;'data v2'!$K$5;'data v2'!$M$3:$M$13))))

And I tried the "I"m so smart" way (with just **"CMD"**+**"workdays"** and when friday+PM or saturday or sunday = next monday + "workdays"):

> =if(isblank(B2);"";IFS(C2=true;WORKDAY.INTL(B2+1;H2;11);weekday(B2)=7;WORKDAY.INTL(B2+2;H2;11);weekday(B2)=1;WORKDAY.INTL(B2+1;H2;11);and(weekday(B2)>1;weekday(B2)<7);WORKDAY.INTL(B2;H2;11);and(C2=true;weekday=6);WORKDAY.INTL(B2+1;H2;1)))

And tried to find some way to turn theses days into next monday

> =IF(WEEKDAY(B50;3)=0;B50;1)

> =B51+MOD(9-B51;7)

> =B2+MOD(9-WEEKDAY(B2);7)

And finally thought "hey, let's make it simple !" Guess what.. did not work

> =WORKDAY.INTL(B49;H49;11)

Do someone has a solution before I start crying ?

Many thanks if you read this

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.
Here is the link to the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IdpuhR44UaNUz9U8xD9mzWXLiJLAF0lHd9gPPHhNANU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome! Don't cry - no formula is worth tears. Moreover, the task is not as difficult as it might seem. I would be grateful if you could create a table with test data, with the "SHIPMENT/WORKDAYS" table and with the table shown in the screenshot, and add a link to this spreadsheet in the question text: the most boring part of preparing the answer is to manually retype the test data from their photo...

Comment: Hey JohnSUN, Thanks for your message ! 
You're right, I forgot to post the link of it. I edited my post

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IdpuhR44UaNUz9U8xD9mzWXLiJLAF0lHd9gPPHhNANU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: While links to external resources might be helpful, questions on this site should be self contained. Show what you have tried including sample data , what you found from this site, from the official resources for end-users and why they didn't meet your needs. Please [edit] your question to provide the requested details directly into the question body. If you need further help, please read first [Guides to ask a \[google-sheets\] question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4935/88163).

Comment: Dear friend, I have doubts about row 4. I counted it on my fingers several times - the parcel should arrive on Monday 03/04/23 (lundi). Why do you have Tuesday (mardi)?

Comment: @JohnSUN "Why do you have Tuesday (mardi)?" simple: Mardi (Tues) is the 5th next working day (so exclude Sat/Sun in between) because it is **Workdays** which has been selected in the formula.

Comment: @24601 Well, in the description of the task, Saturday is excluded only as the day of dispatch (out day), Sunday is excluded as the day of issue. It's a delivery, great mail forwarding service - is the post office closed on Sunday? Issue of parcels is not made on Sunday, and logistics, the actual transportation of postal parcels (as far as I know) does not stop for a minute.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the purpose of **WORKDAYS** in the context of Sheets. Whether *you* might work on a Samedi or Dimanche is irrelevant in this case. That's what the OP has selected to perform.

Comment: Hi everyone, I was unable these last days but I would like to thanks all of you for your kind messages and your help. About what you said JohnSUN , the company which will deal with the command works from monday to friday noon, and the companies which delivers works from monday to saturday. So it's supposed to be delivered on monday (as sunday won't count). I might admit that @blind-spots gave a perfect answer which match with my question AND made me learn about MAP en LET function. I still have a lot to learn. Many thanks to all of you. I hope this case will help people as it did for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Formula

The core of the formula is
`=WORKDAY.INTL(startdate; days; 11)`

`11` means Sunday is the only non-work day

```
=WORKDAY.INTL(A2; D2+
   IFS(OR(WEEKDAY(A2)=1; WEEKDAY(A2)=7); 1;
       AND(WEEKDAY(A2)=6; B2); 2;
       B2; 1; TRUE; 0); 
 11)
```

| Weekday | Offset | Formula |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AM - Sunday PM - Sunday AM - Saturday PM - Saturday | 1 | <sup>**Count from Monday**</sup> `OR(WEEKDAY(A2)=1; WEEKDAY(A2)=7); 1` <sub>*Sunday is **always** skipped, offsetting Sat and Sun by 1 has the same effect.*</sub> |
| PM - Friday | 2 | <sup>**Count from Monday**</sup> `AND(WEEKDAY(A2)=6; B2); 2` |
| PM - Monday PM - Tuesday PM - Wednesday PM - Thursday | 1 | <sup>**Add 1 Day**</sup> `B2; 1` |
| AM - Monday AM - Tuesday AM - Wednesday AM - Thursday AM - Friday | 0 | <sup>**No Offset**</sup> `TRUE; 0` |

[image]

#### Single-Cell Solution

The formula above is adapted by mapping the values into a LAMBDA function so that a single formula in `E2` will populate all the rows.

```
=MAP(A2:A; B2:B; D2:D; LAMBDA(a; b; d; IF(a<>"";
   WORKDAY.INTL(a; d+
     IFS(OR(WEEKDAY(a)=1; WEEKDAY(a)=7); 1;
         AND(WEEKDAY(a)=6; b); 2;
         b; 1; TRUE; 0); 
   11); IFERROR(1/0))))
```

[image]